# C ++ ifstream I/O?

Tags: c++, io, fstream

I'm experimenting with C++ file I/O, specifically fstream.  I wrote the following bit of code and as of right now it is telling me that there is no getline member function.  I have been told (and insisted still) that there is a member function getline.  Anybody know how to use the getline member function for fstream?  Or perhaps another way of getting one line at a time from a file?  I'm taking in two file arguments on the command line with unique file extensions.

./fileIO foo.code foo.encode

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>  
#include <queue>
#include <iomanip>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  // convert the C-style command line parameter to a C++-style string,
  // so that we can do concatenation on it
  assert( argc == 2 );
  const string foo = argv[1];

  string line;string codeFileName = foo + ".code";

  ifstream codeFile( codeFileName.c_str(), ios::in );
  if( codeFile.is_open())
  {
  getline(codeFileName, line);
  cout << line << endl;
  }
  else cout << "Unable to open file" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any `include`s? And "I've been told (and insisted still)..." - really? There's documentation for this, check it if you have any doubts. And it's free and easy to use!

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I fixed it above!

Comment: And how you're trying to use this `getline`? You're calling `getline(codeFileName, line);` - both are `string`s, none is `ifstream`.

Comment: What do you mean none if ifstream?

Answer (score 1):

```
getline(codeFileName, line);
```

Should be

```
getline(codeFile, line);
```

You're passing in the file name, not the stream.

By the way, the [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) you're using is a free function, not a member function. In fact, one should avoid the [member function `getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline). It's much harder to use, and harkens back to a day when there was no `string` in the standard library.

Comment: Ah, I see.  It compiles now.  Thanks! Now it says it is unable to open the file, but I will play with it before I ask for any more help.

Comment: @SeanHellebusch From how you're calling it, it looks like you're trying to open a file called `"foo.code.code"` rather than `"foo.code"`

Answer (score 1):

Typo

```
getline(codeFileName, line);
```

should be

```
getline(codeFile, line);
```

I guess the lesson is you have to learn how to interpret compiler error messages. We all make certain kinds of mistakes and learn the compiler errors they tend to generate.

Comment: Very true, and I am very new to C++. Thanks again.